# Android Realm database delete builder

Tags: android, realm

I am replacing `ORMLite` with `Realm` in my project.

We have `RealmQuery` for `QueryBuilder`

What is similar for `DeleteBuilder` ?

> How can I replace DeleteBuilder query with Realm API
>
> To my knowledge Realm just support to delete the Table and Database
>   itself. What if when I have to delete record with some query (as we
>   can do with DeleteBuilder)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a DeleteBuilder as such, instead we have removal methods on most Realm classes:

```
Foo obj = realm.where(Foo.class).findFirst(); // Find a single object;
obj.deleteFromRealm(); // Delete the object from Realm

RealmResults<Foo> list = realm.where(Foo.class).findAll(); // Find all objects;
list.deleteAllFromRealm(); // delete all items that matched your query
list.deleteFromRealm(0); // Delete item at specific index.

realm.delete(Foo.class); // delete all Foo's
realm.deleteAll(); // delete all data in Realm but preserve the schema
```